# GridLayout fill only one column leaving other columns empty

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` with 3 columns and random amount of children inside, I want every children to fill one and only one column, no less and no more.
But the code below makes the `TextView`s fill more than that. I want each `TextView` to fill *1/3* of the space.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:columnCount="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="#abcdef"
        app:viewAspectRatio="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="#fedcba"
        app:viewAspectRatio="3" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

---

If its not possible with `GridLayout`, I'd love to know about other possibilities

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure but try this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:columnCount="3">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="#abcdef"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="#fedcba" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

or :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:columnCount="3">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="#abcdef"
    app:viewAspectRatio="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="#fedcba"
    app:viewAspectRatio="1" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: `viewAspectRatio` is not a property of `TextView` or `GridLayout`. Its a custom attr that I just forgot to remove

Comment: android:layout_columnSpan="1"   Try to add this to your TextViews :)  Like this it will only take one column of your gridview